# MarkLogic: XQuery to Get Distinct Names from XML Document?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I am using the following file:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am using the following query to get the names from the XML document

```
for $x at $i in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*
return fn:distinct-values(name($x))
```

I am getting following results:

```
title
author
year
price
title
author
year
price
title
author
author
author
author
author
year
price
title
author
year
price
```

Instead I just want the distinct one as shown below.

```
title
author
year
price
```

I believe I messed up the for loop. Can someone help me with a fix for this? I tried using distinct-values(). No luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name($x)` contains name of element that currently referenced by variable `$x`. And `$x` always references one element at a time, so calling `distinct-values()` on `name($x)` won't be useful. Instead, you want to call `distinct-values()` on a collection containing all the elements name, like for example :

```
let $result := 
    for $x at $i in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*
    return name($x)
return fn:distinct-values($result)
```

This can also be achieved using plain XPath expression as follow :

```
distinct-values(doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*/name(.))
```

Comment: thanks for helping out. Xpath one is sweet and short. It works. Thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

You were calling `distinct-values()` within the for loop, once for each item in the sequence returned by your expression. Instead pass the result of `for` expression to `distinct-values()`:

```
fn:distinct-values(
  for $x at $i in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*
  return name($x)
)
```

One side note: `node-name()` or `local-name()` are generally recommended over `name()`. Use the former when you need the [qualified name](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#expanded-Qname) of the element and the latter when you only want the string value.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. this solution works as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try simplest one

```
let $x := doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book
return distinct-values($x/name())
```