# distinct elements based on sorting order

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want distinct title of book based on descending
Referring to [MarkLogic: XQuery to Get Distinct Names from XML Document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560761/marklogic-xquery-to-get-distinct-names-from-xml-document)

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Code

```
 let $result := 
     for $x at $i in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*
     order by $x/price descending
     return name($x)
  return fn:distinct-values($result)
```

Comment: Your sample data seems to have distinct titles anyway so it is not clear what the problem is and which title and order you want if there are two `book` elements with the same `title` but a different price. Consider to edit the question and show us some sample data for the input and the corresponding result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
distinct-values(
  for $book in bookstore/book
  order by $book/price descending
  return $book/title
)
```

you get

```
XQuery Kick Start
Learning XML
Everyday Italian
Harry Potter
```

Comment: thks i expect this output only but why distinct-values(---) was working but ```return fn:distinct-values($result)```

Comment: When you select `for $x at $i in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/*` you select all the child elements of the `book` elements and the child elements don't have a `price` child at all.

Comment: To learn for oneself I find it useful to take each piece by itself and see what that does.   First, since you are not using $i dont include "at $i", then try just the two examples and when you figure out why those are different you will have your answer.

for $x in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book/* return $x/price
for $x in doc("bookstore.xml")/bookstore/book   return $x/price